# How to insert an email address from a .net front end into an Oracle table?

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

Right now we get a colon where the @ sign should be when we try to insert an email address coming from .net Front End into an Oracle Table. How can we get around this?

Comment: From .net or the insert in Oracle?

Comment: When stepping through the .net code I can see the email addy has the correct syntax with the @ sign. Once I step through the save part it goes into a direct insert statement on oracle to a field that is a varchar2. When I vew the data in the Oracle table the email addy now has a colon in it instead of the @ sign.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the .Net code you are using.

If the string is not being changed on the .Net side before being sent to Oracle, I would look for any triggers on that table that could be updating the value.